# Error : Field job in required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.JobLauncher' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

The below are my 2 classes for the App and the config

```
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

public class Configuration {
    @Bean
    Job testRun() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job testRun;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("RUNNING ...");
        jobLauncher.run(testRun, null);
    }   

}
```

However, when I try to execute this, I am getting the error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jobLauncher in com.spark.spring.App required a bean of type org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher in your configuration.
```

Am I missing something here? I believe I do have both a JobLauncher and Job bean defined. Also why do I need to define a bean for the Job Launcher?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `Configuration` class a Spring configuration class, meaning annotate it with `@Configuration` as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    Job testRun() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Moreover, according to the error you reported, you need to define a bean of type `JobLauncher` in that configuration class (or somewhere else), or add the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation which will create it automatically for you:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    Job testRun() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the spring-boot-starter-parent version in pom.xml. Try setting it to 2.7.9 version or an earlier version.

Comment: The problem does not depend on Spring Boot version